# Positive Characteristic exponent, then $\lVert x(t)\rVert\to 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> > Let $x(t)$ be any solution to the ODE $x'=a(t)x$. Say that $x(t)$ has strong characteristic exponent $\beta$ as $t\to\infty$ ($t\to-\infty$) if $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\ln\lVert x(t)\rVert=\beta$ ($\lim_{t\to -\infty}\frac{1}{t}\ln\lVert x(t)\rVert=\beta$). We write $\beta=e_+(x(t))$ resp. $e_{-}(x(t))=\beta$.

Now suppose that $e_{+}(x(t))=e_{-}(x(t))=\beta >0$ for a solution $x(t)$ of the ODE.

Let $x_1, x_2$ be two linearly independent solutions of the ODE.

Show that then $\lVert x_i(t)\rVert\to 0$ ($i=1,2$).

---

Take $i=1$.
I do not have an idea how to show that. From the definition I know that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\ln\lVert x_1(t)\rVert=\beta,\\
\lim_{t\to -\infty}\frac{1}{t}\ln\lVert x(t)\rVert=\beta.
$$

No idea how to continue...

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: If you take $\dot{x} = x$, then the solutions are $x(t) = x_0 e^t$ with $\beta = 1$, but if $x_0 \neq 0$ you have $x(t) \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: Ok, you gave a counterexample, thank you. I think the statement should be, that from $\lim_{\lvert t\rvert\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\ln\lVert x(t)\rVert=\beta > 0$ it follows that $\lVert x(t)\rVert\to 0$ as $t\to -\infty$.